# How to achieve mutual exclusion on a database record in linq sql

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, linq-to-sql

I have a distributed client server system which has multiple 'worker' engines and a WCF service, lets call it, `FileManagerService`, which adds 'jobs' to a database for the 'worker' engines to pick up and process.

The database consists of two tables: `Jobs` and `File`. Every job operates on a `File` ( many to one relationship ). Multiple jobs can be added to the `Jobs` table at once, they are processed in the fashion of a queue.

Example of `Job`'s are actions such as : MoveFile or DeleteFile, etc.

I am trying to achieve mutual exclusion on the `File` record by using a 'locked' ( bool ) column in the `File` table itself.

The mutual exclusion zones that I think are needed are within the WCF service `FileManagerService`'s method: `addJob()` and within the 'worker' engines' `TakeAndProcessAJob()`.

At the moment I am having trouble with working out how linq-to-sql deferred execution and how the linq-to-sql transaction system works.

I currently have the following method which is supposed to take a `Job` from the `Jobs` table, check if its related `File` is locked, if it is locked we will return nothing, if it is not locked we will lock the `File` and return a `Job`, and delete that `Job` from the `Jobs` queue:

```
public static Job GetAnAvailableJob()
{
    using (DBDataContext db = new DBDataContext())
    {
        DataLoadOptions loadOptions = new DataLoadOptions();
        loadOptions.LoadWith<Job>(f => f.File);
        db.LoadOptions = loadOptions;
        var jobAvailable = from ja in db.Jobs
                                    where ja.File.locked == false
                                    select ja;
        var jobToTake = jobAvailable.FirstOrDefault();
        // This file temp is here so that we can return
        // an associated File with the Job.
        // We delete
        File fileTemp = null;
        if (jobToTake != null)
        {
            fileTemp = jobToTake.File;
            jobAvailable.File.locked = true;
            Console.WriteLine("Locked file:" + fileTemp.FileID);
            db.Jobs.DeleteOnSubmit(jobToTake);
            db.SubmitChanges();
            jobToTake.Asset = fileTemp;
        }
        return jobToTake;
    }
}
```

The 'worker' engines `TakeAndProcessAJob()` basically does the following: Call `GetAnAvailableJob()`, if return object is not null -> proccess the job, if it is null -> sleep.

The WCF Service `FileManagerService` uses this locking method:

```
public static bool LockAsset(long FileID)
{
    using (DBDataContext db = new DBDataContext())
    {
        var fileToLock = db.Files.Where(f => f.FileID == FileID && f.locked == false).Single();
        if (fileToLock == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Locked File:" + fileToLock.AssetID);
            fileToLock.locked = true;
            db.SubmitChanges();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

What do I need to change in these two methods to make then behave in a transactional manner and have mutual exclusion on the `File` record. Currently I am getting change conflict exceptions - row not changed or found - on the `SubmitChanges()` within the `TakeAndProcessAJob()` method.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not figure out the answer to my question and so I did some logic restructuring and devised a workaround using plain old SQL. To lock the record I now use a single line ( atomic ) command on the record:

`UPDATE dataTable SET locked = 'True' WHERE (locked = 'False') AND (recordID= 15)`

I then use `SqlDataReader` and check the `RecordsAffected` field. If records have changed, it means that I have successfully locked the record. If records have not changed, it means the record is already locked, and so I return `false` on my locking method.

The process that is trying to lock the record then sits in a while loop calling `lockRecord` and waiting for a successful callback.

I'm not sure if it was completely necessary to make the switch from LINQ to SQL. I made the logic changes in my application, and the switch to plan SQL at the same time and so it is difficult to identify if using LINQ was THE problem.

Answer (score 0):

That "row not changed or found" error can be something as simple as your database model file not matching the actual physical database schema.

Another reason might be that LINQ didn't detect any changes to submit. Say if the record you were selecting was already true and you mark it as true. You could avoid this by not updating if its already true or possibly the cause is there's a setting on the modal file under the properties for that field on the table that you can actually turn off UpdateCheck, but it doesn't sound like thats what you want.

In an unrelated story:
doesn't ".Single()" throw an error when nothing is found as aposed to firstOrDefault() which just returns null ?